# Google PlayStore PEPK tool. Where is the encrypted output stored?

Tags: encryption, google-play-services

I am struggling to complete the Google App Signing procedure and have managed to download and run the PEPK tool with no errors. It is not at all helpful to have the entered password characters blanked out, by the way.

My question is where is the encrypted output hidden as this thing just ends with no message at all.

Answer (score 0):

The output goes wherever you specify in the "--output" flag passed to PEPK. If you don't specify a path for "--output" it will put it right in where the pepk.jar is. Make sure you are doing things with a user that has permissions to create a file.

Example:
java -jar pepk.jar --keystore=foo.keystore --alias=foo --output=private_key.pem --encryptionkey=abcd0ff8fb833b65abcdefb839de6a

In this example "private_key.pem" will get created in the same directory where the pepk.jar is created.